# How to import excel file using HTML Input file and read the file contents in Node.js (How to send the fullpath to Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, import, html-input

I have bit of confusion regarding the reading of file using HTML, AngularJS and Node.js. Since I am bit confused I am hoping someone can guide me with this.

I am trying to import a file using HTML and Angularjs and it is working fine. I am able to import a file but I am not sure how can I send the whole file to Node.js. Due to Browser restrictions, I am unable to get the full path of the file so I am just wondering if I can not send the full path then how can I access the data of the Excel file in Node.js.

Here is the code that I am working on:

```
<div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" fileUploader="uploadFile" class="custom-file-input"></input>
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">{{ FileName }}</label>
</div>
```

My `angularjs` function that should obtain the FILEPATH and sent it to the corresponding NODE.JS:

```
app.directive('fileUploader', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var onChangeHandler = scope.$eval(attrs.fileUploader);
      element.on('change', onChangeHandler);
      element.on('$destroy', function() {
        element.off();
      });

    }
  };
});

app.controller('TemplatesController',function($scope){
        
    $scope.FileName     =   "Choose a Excel File";
    
    //Import an Excel File from the Local System
    $scope.uploadFile = function(event){
        var files = event.target.files;
        $scope.FileName = files[0].name;
        console.log($scope.FileName)
        $http({
            url     : "/UploadFIle",
            method  : "post",
            file    : files[0] //PATH OF THE FILE WHICH I AM UNABLE TO GET
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });


    };
});
```

My `index.js` which will route to respective Node Control file:

```
//Read the Excel File Data
app.post('/UploadFIle',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    ReadExcelFile.ReadExcelFileContent(req.body,function(data){
        console.log("INDEX JS");
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

My `Node.js` function that will read the data from obtained file:

```
//ReadExcelFile.js

const xlsxFile      =   require('read-excel-file/node');

exports.ReadExcelFileContent    =   function(req,callback){
    
    var fileLocation    =   req.path; //NOT SURE HOW TO ACCESS THE FILEPATH HERE BECAUSE I WANT TO READ THE DATA HERE
    console.log(fileLocation);
}
```

Also, after the file upload I am trying to change the name of `FileName` but seems like two way data binding is not working due to which in the HTML page it does not display the `FileName` that I just uploaded.

Hello again, I tried many things to send the path of the read file to Node.js but none of them are working. How can I resolve this?

Comment: The method on angular code is `get`  (method  : "get",) and you are waiting/listening for `post` in node.js. check if this is the problem.

Comment: @Mu-Majid Thanks for the response. No, actually I was trying a few things that is when I might have messed up this thing. It's actually `POST` because I need to send the path of the file

Comment: @Mu-Majid Any idea how to make this work? Tried few more things but no luck

Comment: check my answer, i have attached an article explaining step by step the backend and the frontend sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question, You cannot access your OS' file system because JavaScript in browser has no access to the File System.

I have found [this article](https://ciphertrick.com/file-upload-with-angularjs-and-nodejs/) which explains how to handle file upload both on the backend (NodeJS/ExpressJS) and the frontend (AngularJS).

The frontend example uses `ng-file-upload` module.

Now you can choose a file from your disk, upload it and send it to your NodeJS server and access the file data after your multer middleware runs (explained in the article). Hope i t helps :).

Answer (score 1):

why are you send your file path? after you add a file to input tag in UI, it have your file. then  you want to send that file to `node.js`

```
app.controller('TemplatesController',function($scope){
        
    $scope.FileName     =   "Choose a Excel File";
    
    //Import an Excel File from the Local System
    $scope.uploadFile = function(event){
        var files = event.target.files;
        $scope.FileName = files[0].name;
        console.log($scope.FileName)
        $http({
            url     : "/UploadFIle",
            method  : "post",
            file    : files[0] // send your file
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });


    };
});
```

also you can change your file name like that

```
app.controller('TemplatesController',function($scope){
        
    $scope.FileName     =   "Choose a Excel File";
    
    //Import an Excel File from the Local System
    $scope.uploadFile = function(event){
        var files = event.target.files;
        files[0].name = 'xxxxx'  // change file name 
        $scope.FileName = files[0].name;
        console.log($scope.FileName)
        $http({
            url     : "/UploadFIle",
            method  : "post",
            file    : files[0] // send your file
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });


    };
});
```

after you can save that file in any place using nodejs

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I am trying to send the path because I want to read the Excel file data in the node.js. I tried the `Angularjs Controller` method with `file    : files[0] // send your file` but here I would be sending `just name` of the file right? How can node.js know where is it located? Also in the `index.js` when I try to `console.log(req.body)` then I get `{}` meaning that it is unable to get anything. Do I have to change anything for `file` type because normally when we send `data` we can directly access it in the `node.js`. I have edited the code please check once.

Comment: try this one and `$http.post(url, JSON.stringify({file: files[0] }))then(function (response) { console.log(response)})` then console.log(req.body) in node.js

Comment: I tried as you mentioned. I get the following result in `index.js`: '{ file: {} }'. Just wanted to confirm do we have to send as `file` or `data` in angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

Because angular is just JS code that run on the browser so it can't access file system. What you have to do is upload the file to your back-end server, then the server parse the excel file with a library like `SheetJS` and return the file content as JSON back to the client